# Hklm/Init on Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce

I've been trying to make my application run at startup on windows CE 6.0, unfortunately since the device (YFAtlas4) is customized by manufacturer I'm unable to place shortcut in \Windows\Startup. (for some misterious reasons) 
So now I'm trying to place path to my application in Hklm\Init registry key, and here's my problem: I's there a way to place absolute path there ? In every example that I've seen there's only application name, and my application has to be instaled in \ResidentFlash\ folder.

Comment: Post exactly what you tried to do so we can see if there is a mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put the full path there?
There should not be any problem doing so.

If you edit your registry using code, then the string you want to store is `L"\\ResidentFlash\\AppName.exe"`. Alternatively, in case you have an ActiveSync connection with the device you can use a [remote registry editor](http://ceregeditor.mdsoft.pl/index.php?id=3&lang=en) and not mess with the double backslashes.

Also, since you are using the `HKLM\Init` functionality - make sure your application calls [`SignalStarted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488242.aspx) so other programs that are dependent on it can start as well.

Answer (score 1):

A fully qualified path should be supported jusy fine.  Be aware that if the path has a space in it, you'll need to quote delimit it.  Also, if it's a Compact Framework app, it's not as simple as just adding your app to the Init key - often that will fail.  See [this blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/15/AutolaunchingCFAppsWithTheHKLMInitRegistryKey.aspx) on getting CF apps working with the Init key.